# proof that quaternion group is a group

Tags: quaternions

My textbook gives the following definition of a quaternion group:
$Q = \{\pm 1, \pm i, \pm j, \pm k\}$, where multiplication is defined by: 
\begin{align*}
1*x &= x &
(-1)*x &= -x & 
(-1)*(-x)&=x
\end{align*}
for $x = 1,i,j,k$ (**NOTE**: x does not include -1,-i,-j,-k). Moreover, 
\begin{align*}
i^2= j^2= k^2 = -1,
\end{align*}
and
\begin{align*}
ij&=k & jk&=i & ki&=j, \\
ji&=-k &  kj&=-i & ki&=-j.
\end{align*}

The question it then poses is: prove that this is a group. i.e. prove associativity, that 1 is the unit element, and that every element has an inverse.

I am stuck at trying to prove even the simple statement that $1*-1=-1$. I have no idea how to prove it, after having fruitlessly shuffled formulas for an hour.
Am I missing something?

Comment: Well, $1*(-1)=-1$ by your very first rule “$1*x=x$”.

Comment: @Lubin, the OP's parenthetical **NOTE** excludes $x=-1$ from the rule $1*x=x$.

Comment: There is definitely something missing here.  If you systematically replace the symbols, $1,-1,i,-i,j-j,k,-k$ with less suggestive symbols, say $a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h$, and do not make any assumption about the operation $*$, then the result of $a*b$ is completely undefined; it could be *anything*.

Comment: Well, @BarryCipra, the parenthetical note is wrong, unless the book’s author was thinking that he was giving a minimal description. But I doubt very much that that description was complete. If I was to be constrained by the exclusion of those four from the rules, I would have to agree with OP that $1*(-1)$ seemed undeterminable.

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of ways of doing this.

1) Brute force. Changing notation, write $e_1 = i, e_2 = j, e_3 = k$. Then the rules above become $e_i e_j = - e_j e_i$ for $i\not = j$ and $e_i^2 = -1$. We want to show that $(e_i e_j)e_k = e_i(e_j e_k)$, and we can at least assume without loss of generality that $i\leq j \leq k$. Some further symmetry will reduce the number of cases you have to check, but it still requires some explicit computation.

2) Introducing the Levi-Civita symbol $\epsilon_{ijk}$ and Kronecker delta $\delta_{ij}$, we can rewrite the defining rules for multipication in $Q$ as
\begin{align*}
e_i e_j = \epsilon_{ijk} e_k - \delta_{ij}
\end{align*}
(with implicit summation over $k$). Now just write out $e_i (e_j e_k)$ and $(e_i e_j) e_k$, churn through the calculus, and show that they agree. (Proving associativity for products involving the identity $1$ or the central element $-1$ is trivial.) The trick is noting that
\begin{align*}
\delta_{ij} e_j &= e_i &
\epsilon_{ijk} &= -\epsilon_{jik} &
\epsilon_{ijk}\epsilon_{pqr} &= \delta_{jq}\delta_{kr} - \delta_{jr}\delta_{kq}
\end{align*}
(with implicit summation throughout), which allows us to reduce such expressions formally.

This method is probably overkill, but you'll do this sort of thing countless times if you take a quantum mechanics class (or have done it countless times if you have taken a quantum mechanics class), so you might as well do it now.

3) So, where does this group actually come from? There's a quaternion algebra $\mathbb{H}$ defined as algebra (over $\mathbb{R}$ with basis $1, e_1, e_2, e_3$ satisfying the same relation as for $Q$. (It's clear that $Q$ is associative iff $\mathbb{H}$ is, which would be more useful to us if we knew that $\mathbb{H}$ is associative.) The action of $\mathbb{H}$ on itself induces an embedding $\rho:Q \to SU(2)$. Unwinding this map gives an embedding
\begin{align*}
1 &\to \begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix} &
e_1 & \to \begin{pmatrix} i & 0 \\ 0 & -i\end{pmatrix} &
e_2 & \to \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ -1 & 0 \end{pmatrix} &
e_3 & \to \begin{pmatrix} 0 & i \\ i & 0 \end{pmatrix}
\end{align*}
with $\rho(-x) = -\rho(x)$ for all $x$. (See also the Pauli matrices, which is just the same computation on the physics side of things.) The point is that associativity is clear, since $SU(2)$ is a group. I'm not going to slog through the computation here, but there's a similar faithful representation $Q \to SL_2(\mathbb{F}_3)$.

In this particular case, I don't think you can get away from doing some sort of computation, but it's good to know that this group $Q$ comes from somewhere.

Comment: I agree. Proving associativity from the multiplication table is prohibitively inefficient.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

first prove associativity, than, from your rules, for $x=1$ you have $-1*(1)=-1$ and:
$$
1*(-1)=1*(-1*(1))=(1*(-1))*1=(-1)*1=-1
$$